# subprocess in Python hangs

Tags: python, perl, command, buffer, subprocess

I am trying to retrieve some information from a Perl script using Python and subprocess:

```
command = ["perl","script.perl","arg1.txt","<","arg2.txt"]
print " ".join(command)
p = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
text = p.stdout.read()
```

The join-statement simply prints the command as I would enter it in the terminal for double-checking the quality of the command. That one always works... But within Python, it hangs at the `subprocess.Popen()` (at p= ... ).

I also tried several other `methods` such as `call()` but to no avail.

It only outputs one line of text, so I don't know how that could be the problem.

Comment: You could try to run Python with `strace -ff` to discover exactly what operation makes it hang.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to involve the shell if you only want a simple input redirection. Open the file in Python, and pass the file handle to `Popen` via the `stdin` argument.

```
with open("arg2.txt") as infile:
     command = ["perl", "script.perl", "arg1.txt"]
     p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=infile)
     text = p.stdout.read()
```

or

```
command = "perl script.perl arg1.txt < arg2.txt"
p = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
text = p.stdout.read()
```

---

With a list *and* `shell=True`, it's not clear to me why it the call to `perl` blocks. When I try something like

```
subprocess.call("cat < .bashrc".split(), shell=True)
```

it blocks as if it is still trying to read from the inherited standard input. If I provide it with input using

```
subprocess.call("cat < .bashrc".split(), shell=True, stdin=open("/dev/null"))
```

the call returns immediately. In either case, it appears that `cat` is ignoring its further arguments.